# Triangle inequality for three arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vectors

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be vectors. How do we prove that $|a + b + c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$?

I was able to prove that $|a + b + c| < |a| + |b| + |c|$. How do I complete the proof?

[image: OP's work on the problem]

Comment: Its a little bit confusing to me.Would you mind explaining it again? Thank you

Comment: @nbro  that 4$ and 6$ part? And the way to prove that L.H.S=R.H.S with that?

Comment: In other words, you cannot prove it because it is not true (unless some additional restrictions are put on $a, b, c$).

Comment: The problem appears to be: 1. The original (assigned?) question asked for a proof that if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are vectors, then $|a + b + c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$. 2. This got broken into two conditions, "$<$ _and_ $=$", when it logically meant "$<$ _or_ $=$" (and should not have been separated into cases). 3. OP was happy with the "less-than case", and appeared to ask about equality. 4. In the manner of a game of telephone, an edit changed the meaning of the question, so that the task ("prove equality") as stated is incorrect.

Comment: I concur with @AndrewD.Hwang's explanation of the events leading to the current sorry state of the question. Note that "Prove that  |a+b+c|<|a|+|b|+|c|" is wrong as well.

Comment: @user405589: I rolled back the version and made some re-wording changes that attempt to capture your thinking. If anything doesn't match your intent, please edit to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two critiques on the work so far:

1. An inequality "$A \leq B$" means "$A < B$ *or* $A = B$". Splitting the proof into "cases" is usually not necessary, and is not necessary here.

   If splitting *were* necessary, the structure of a typical proof would be: "If $A = B$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, $A \neq B$. [Proof that if $A \neq B$, then $A < B$.]"

   Note, incidentally, that "$A < B$ *and* $A = B$" is a contradiction: The usual meanings of the less-than and equality symbols are logically incompatible. This highlights that fact that the proof *cannot* be separated into first proving strict inequality and then equality.
2. If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are vectors, there is no reason that $a + b + c = 0$, and therefore no reason that they constitute sides of a triangle.

   If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are points such that $a = OA$, etc., the sides of the triangle are $(B - A)$, $(C - B)$, and $(C - A)$, whose sum *is* zero. Since these vectors are (for present purposes) unrelated to $a$, $b$, and $c$, the construction in your diagram turns out to be unhelpful.

---

Instead, you probably have seen the ordinary triangle inequality
$$
|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|\quad\text{for all vectors $a$ and $b$.}
\tag{1}
$$
To prove the triangle inequality for *three* summands, apply (1) recursively to $(a + b) + c$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 3):

The triangle inequality states that $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$. We just apply this twice to get:

$$|(a+b)+c|\leq|a+b|+|c|\leq |a|+|b|+|c|$$
and we're done.